# Checking to see if all values in an array are equal

Tags: ruby, array

I have an array that might be either one-dimensional, two-dimension, or three-dimensional. I'm wanting to check to see if all values in a given direction are constant.

Here are 3 functions:

```
# Check to see if all values in the first dimension are equal                                                                                                                                             
def constant1D(arr)
  arr.inject(true) { |same, val| same and val == arr[0] }
end

# Check to see if all values in the second dimension are equal                                                                                                                                            
def constant2Dy(arr)
  arr.inject(true) { |same, x| same and constant1D(x) }
end

# Check to see if all values in the third dimension are equal                                                                                                                                             
def constant3Dz(arr)
  arr.inject(true) { |same, x| same and constant2Dy(x) }
end
```

And here is the code that would be checking:

```
constantX = constant1D(values)
constantY = ((mapType == :twoD) and constant2Dy(values))
constantZ = ((mapType == :threeD) and constant3Dz(values))
```

Here are some sample runs:

```
threeDa = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]]
threeDb = [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9]]]
threeDc = [[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], [[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]], [[7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8], [9, 9, 9]]]
>> constant1D(threeDa)
=> true
>> constant1D(threeDb)
=> false
>> constant1D(threeDc)
=> false
>> constant2Dy(threeDa)
=> false
>> constant2Dy(threeDb)
=> true
>> constant2Dy(threeDc)
=> false
>> constant3Dz(threeDa)
=> false
>> constant3Dz(threeDb)
=> false
>> constant3Dz(threeDc)
=> true
```

Is this the most "Ruby" way, or is there a better way? E.g., referencing `arr[0]` in the above has a little bit of code smell to me, but perhaps I'm overthinking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rewritten]

You want to avoid inject, as `uniq.size` is O(n) and clearer. Monkey patching array makes the code clearer and is idiomatic Ruby. Methods that return a boolean should end in `?`. Method names should be snake_case. Here you go:

```
class Array
  # Check to see if all values in the first dimension are equal
  def constant_1d?
    uniq.size == 1
  end

  # Check to see if all values in the second dimension are equal
  def constant_2dy?
    all?(&:constant_1d?)
  end

  # Check to see if all values in the third dimension are equal
  def constant_3dz?
    all?(&:constant_2dy?)
  end
end
```

Comment: O(N) complexity, good.

Comment: I've verified that this works fine (with `== 1` instead of `.one?`) as a replacement for `constant1D`, but does the `inject` seem bad for the other 2D and 3D checks? For `constant2Dy`, I've verified that I can do `arr.transpose.uniq.size == 1`, but am still pondering `constant3Dz`.

Comment: @Ben Hocking, what do you think?

Comment: `each` is used to perform side-effects, it returns the array being iterated, I don't see how this can be working.

Comment: @dankohn, tested it out with my arrays and it works fine. It's always nice to try thinking in different ways. Thanks!